# How to set padding to Actionbar Sherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to set the custom background drawable to my ActionbarSherlock control. My background has a small bottom shadow. So, I want to set action-bar's bottom padding to the 15dip but I don't know how.
Please help me with some codes.

This is the screen shot of my activity with shadow-background:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should customize the `actionBarSize`, it's fixed:

Here's the dimens file that's referenced by the theme:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default height of an action bar. -->
    <dimen name="abs__action_bar_default_height">40dip</dimen>
    <!-- Vertical padding around action bar icons. -->
    <dimen name="abs__action_bar_icon_vertical_padding">4dip</dimen>
    <!-- Text size for action bar titles -->
    <dimen name="abs__action_bar_title_text_size">16dp</dimen>
    <!-- Text size for action bar subtitles -->
    <dimen name="abs__action_bar_subtitle_text_size">12dp</dimen>
    <!-- Top margin for action bar subtitles -->
    <dimen name="abs__action_bar_subtitle_top_margin">-2dp</dimen>
    <!-- Bottom margin for action bar subtitles -->
    <dimen name="abs__action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin">4dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

The theme:

```
<item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height</item>
```

There's no bottom padding configuration.